# find general solution from linear equations

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

reduced to row-echelon form $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&-2&4\\
2&4&8&1&9\\
3&6&13&4&14\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

i got $$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&0&-19/2&5/2\\
0&0&1&5/2&1/2\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

so i have two equations $$X_1+X_2-19/2X_4+5/2X_5$$ and $$X_3+5/2X_4+X_5/2$$

but im not sure how to make these two into one general solution

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are dealing with the homogeneous system associated to the row-echelon reduced matrix 
$$A\textbf X=\textbf 0,$$ we have to solve:
$$\begin{cases}
X_1+2X_2-\frac{19}2X_4+\frac52X_5=0\\
X_3+\frac 52 X_4+\frac 12 X_5=0
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore we can put $X_1, X_2, X_3$ as parameters, $X_1=t, X_2=s, X_3=v$ and solve the system in the two variables remaining $X_4, X_5$ by standards $2\times 2$ linear systems resolving methods.

Comment: im confused on how you put $X_2=8$? and $X_3=v$ etc?

Comment: You will have at least $\infty^3$ solutions since you have 5 variables and two equations.

Comment: $X_2=s$ not $8$

Comment: $t+2s=19/2X_4-5/2X_5$ and $v=-5/2X_4-1/2X_5$ Let $X_5=-2V-5X_4$ and sub into first equation. $$t+2s=5/2(19X_4+2V+5X_4)$$ I would have 4 unknowns, not sure how to make it to three only @alessandro

Comment: As @aforest said we have $\mbox{dim}\mbox{Ker} M =3$ so we have 3 parameters and two variables.
Let say, the unknowns are $x_4$ and $x_5$ as you have written in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\dim\ker\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&-2&4\\
0&0&2&5&1\\
\end{pmatrix}=3$, personally I'd like to give some zeros and then calculate the others:

- finding $x=\begin{pmatrix}
  a\\
  b\\
  0\\
  0\\
  0\\
  \end{pmatrix}$, we get $a=2,b=-1$
- finding $x=\begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  0\\
  a\\
  b\\
  c\\
  \end{pmatrix}$, we get $a=-22,b=5,c=19$
- finding $x=\begin{pmatrix}
  0\\
  a\\
  b\\
  c\\
  0\\
  \end{pmatrix}$, we get $a=19,b=-10,c=4$

Then$$\ker\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3&-2&4\\
0&0&2&5&1\\
\end{pmatrix}=<\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
-1\\
0\\
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
-22\\
5\\
19\\
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
19\\
-10\\
4\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}>$$

Comment: why equal to 3? and i dont understand how you get the vectors